# How to set the description of a local group to blank

Tags: powershell

Consider the following code:

```
# create test group
New-LocalGroup -Name 'Group1' -Description 'xxx'

# update test group description to blank
Set-LocalGroup -Name 'Group1' -Description '' # fails
Set-LocalGroup -Name 'Group1' -Description $null # fails
```

On the contrary it is possible to create a group without description:

```
New-LocalGroup -Name 'Group2'
```

How is it possible to update the group description of a local group to blank without removing the group first? This happens on PowerShell `5.1`.

Comment: I guess this is a bug knowing that with `ADSI`, you can't just set (some) attributes to a zero length string either (using the `Put` method) but have to use [`x.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/the-putex-method) instead. You might expect that a `Set-LocalGroup` cmdlet whould take care of this when you provide a empty `-Description`.

Comment: Not null or an empty string, but `Set-LocalGroup -Name 'xxx' -Description ' '` works - 1 space character

Comment: That's a visual workaround, but thx for the suggestion. Also thanks to @iRon for the explanation

Comment: I recommend to do a bug report at: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues (if you don't, I am also happy to do it for you).

Comment: To improve the visual workaround, you can set the description like this: `Set-LocalGroup -Name <GROUPNAME> -Description " \`b"`. Technically, the size of the description is 2, but visually 0 due to the backspace character.

Comment: @iRon If you're already on it... another bug: `Set-LocalGroup -Name <GROUPNAME> -Description "\`0"`. Afterwards, the group cannot be deleted or modified anymore XD

Comment: @iRon feel free to do so. I'm sure you're better at these things than I am. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't cover *the other bug*: ``Set-LocalGroup -Name <GROUPNAME> -Description "`0"`` in my answer/bug-report, as I don't think this is PowerShell related but more a Windows issue (are you able the delete/modify it with `lusrmgr.msc`?). In other words, I presume this is more an issue for the [super user](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are some AD attributes that requires the [`Putex` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/the-putex-method), that doesn't count for the `Description` attribute. Meaning my assumption in the initial comment to the question is wrong, and it is possible to clear the `Description` attribute with just the [`Put` method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/the-put-method):

```
$Name = 'Group1'
New-LocalGroup -Name $Name -Description 'xxx'

$Group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./$Name,group"
$Group.Put('Description', '')
$Group.SetInfo()

Get-LocalGroup -Name $Name

Name   Description
----   -----------
Group1
```

The issue lays purely in the cmdlet parameter definitions. Without going into the `C#` programming, you might just pull this from the proxy command:

```
$Command = Get-Command Set-LocalGroup
$MetaData = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]$Command
$ProxyCommand = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
$ProxyCommand

[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium', HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717979')]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]            # <-- Here is the issue
    [ValidateLength(0, 48)]
    [string]
    ${Description},
...
```

In other words, to quick and dirty workaround this with a proxy command:

```
function SetLocalGroup {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium', HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717979')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]            # <-- Modified
        [ValidateLength(0, 48)]
        [string]
        ${Description},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='InputObject', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LocalGroup]
        ${InputObject},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Default', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        
        ${Name},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SecurityIdentifier', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]
        ${SID})

    end {
        if ($Description) { Set-LocalGroup @PSBoundParameters }
        elseif ($Name) {
            $Group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./$Name,group"
            $Group.Put('Description', '')
            $Group.SetInfo()
        }
    }
}

SetLocalGroup -Name 'Group1' -Description ''
```

Related bug report: [**`#16049`** `AllowEmptyString()]` for `-Description` in `Set-LocalGroup`/`SetLocalUser`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16049)

Answer (score 1):

As `Set-LocalGroup` fails on that, the only other way I can think of is using ADSI:

```
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/Group1,group"
$group.Description.Value = [string]::Empty
$group.CommitChanges()
```

It's a workaround of course and I agree with [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041644/how-to-set-the-description-of-a-local-group-to-blank#comment122024196_69041644) you should do a bug report on this.